# Cannot mkdir unless sudo is used

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, permissions

I am accessing my Pi through SSH and I noticed that I cannot `mkdir` anywhere. not even in my own home folder `~/`!! Unless I `sudo`.

I checked the owner and permission of my folder. it is as follow:

`drwxrwxrwx 9 pi pi 4096 Aug 13 10:22 pi`

everything is owned by me, and I even `chmod  777` it just for this once. But still I get `mkdir: cannot create directory x': No space left on device` error when I try to `mkdir`

Obviously there is space left on device because everything works fine if i put `sudo` in front of it. So what is the problem here ?

Comment: Try to use df -h to see how much space is left on your device.

Comment: I should add: raspbian comes with utility to expand partition to fill the entire SD card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem for root. Because on ext filesystems 'root' user has extra %5 reserved space on filesystem while formatting. If that reserved space filled up you will not create file/dir on filesystem neither. Delete some files on your filesystem to get free space.

Answer (score 3):

For those with similar problem, make sure to run raspberry pi config tool. In there you will find a menu that allows you to expand your partition to fill 100℅ of the available space. Otherwise, you will be limited to very small space regardless of your SD card size.

Comment: Good advice! The tool is run with:

    sudo raspi-config

Answer (score -1):

good advice. from UI you need to do following things 
1. Go to Menu
2.select preferences
3. raspberry pi configuration
4. system tab
5. Expand fileSystem.
6. Reboot your Pi